# Robots.txt in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: search-engine, command, robots.txt

I am trying to figure out what to add to my robots.txt file ? Specifically, what does the command

```
Allow: /$
```

do in the robots.txt file ?

**Edit:** Also, how to allow a site to any have its /index page indexed when using ASP.NET MVC ?

Comment: The robots.txt file doesn't actually *do* anything. Your question is "What is the most likely response from users/bots/hackers if I put this line in my robots.txt file?"

Comment: yes - that's true but its essentially a synonymous question with what you've stated really.

Comment: Not really. Many bots don't even read the `robots.txt` file, or worse, deliberately breaks it.